# ROS frame transformation (camera to base)

Tags: python, transformation, frames, ros

I am working with Baxter robot and what I am trying to do is get the position of an object using augmented reality markers and move the hand to that position in order to grasp it.

I am using the `ar_tools` package to get the position/orientation of the object, but that with respect to the `head_camera` which I am using. The last couple of days I've been experimenting with how to change that reference frame (`head_camera`) to the base frame as this frame is used by `moveit` to make the plans. I have tried to set the `frame_id` of the header of the message I receive from the `ar_tools` manually to `'base'`:

```
 pose_target.header.frame_id = 'base'
```

but the position and orientation I am getting are still WRT the `head_camera`. I also tried to do:

```
self.tl.lookupTransform("/base", "/head_camera", self.t)
```

where `self.t = self.tl.getLatestCommonTime("/head_camera", "/base")`, but I was getting an extrapolation error. It was something like

> the transformation requires to extrapolate in the past

(I can't really remember now and I'm not in the lab.) Then I thought I might need to run the `lookupTransform` from the `head_cam` to `head`, from `head` to `torso` and from `torso` to Baxter's `base`.

Could someone guide me on how to change the frame of the marker of the `ar_tools` from `head_camera` to `base`?

Also, for the extrapolation error, is there a way to do this in a static way?

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly more straightforwards way to do this, presuming you're reviving a `PoseStamped` message from `ar_tools`:

```
on_received_pose(pose):
    '''
    Handler for your poses from ar_tools
    '''
    if self.tl.waitForTransform(pose.header.frame_id, "/base", pose.header.stamp, rospy.Duration(0.1)): # this line prevents your extrapolation error, it waits up to 0.1 seconds for the transform to become valid
        transd_pose = self.tl.transformPose("/base",pose)
        # do whatever with the transformed pose here
    else:
        rospy.logwarn('Couldn\'t Transform from "{}" to "/base"  before timeout. Are you updating TF tree sufficiently?'.format(pose.header.frame_id))
```

You're getting that extrapolation error likely because the transform network wasn't fully formed at the time you got your first message; `tf` refuses to extrapolate, it will only interpolate, so if you haven't received at least one transform message for every frame both before and after (or exactly at) the timestamp you're trying to transform to, it will throw an exception. That added `if` statement checks to see if it can actually perform the transform before trying to do so. You could of course also just surround the `transformPose()` call in a `try/catch` block instead, but I feel that for `tf` this makes it more explicit what you're trying to do.

In general, check out the simple [ROS tf Python Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/TfUsingPython) for more examples/modes of operation.

Comment: hello, thanks and sorry for the late reply! I tried this and it would have worked perfectly but there is a slight problem. I just figured out that the message im receiving from the ar_pose has no stamp!  here are the messages : (http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/ar_pose/html/msg/ARMarker.html). Is there a way to do this without having the timestamp? Is there a way to add a timestamp to the message? Thanks again for you quick reply and help!

Comment: EDIT :  sorry i thought the message did not have a timestamp but when i printed it it returned `stamp: secs: 1429124219` so i guess this means it has one!

Comment: that kind of things happen to you when you try to ask something and you are not in the lab! Sorry aruisdante the extrapolation was in the **future** and not in the **past** and i guess this changes a lot..

Comment: Well, it's the same problem, but from a slightly different prospective. It means that the rest of your transform network is a bit behind the AR pose's frame. You need to use the `waitForTransform()` method described in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28Python%29). I've updated my example to show this.

Comment: @ekptwtos updated question to wait for the transform to be valid.

Comment: sorry for the delay, that could still not perform the transformation for some reason, what i did was actually to use the `moveit` command `set_pose_reference_frame(pose_target.header.frame_id)` to make the planner of moveit to plan to the frame of the camera! thanks a lot for your time